# Invite 100+ guests to Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events, google-calendar-reminders

I need to invite 250 emails to a Google Calendar event. I was able to add the first 100 without any hassle. But any invite after that would give me an error, "Oops, we couldn't update this event. Please try again in a few minutes".

After hours of trial and error, I discovered that I can invite one guest to my event every 30 minutes. This is extremely time consuming and inefficient.

How can I resolve this issue and invite ~250 guests at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add the event participants to a Google group

- You can invite up to 200 guests to a Google Calendar Event
- However, a [Google Group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/46601?hl=en) counts as one guest
- A Google Group can have up to 2000 members
- If you add multiple participants to the same group  and invite to your event the group instead of the single participants  - you can reduce the number of guests below the allowed limit.

References:

- [Guest limit for invitations](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37161?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:%7E:text=Guest%20limit%20for%20invitations,have%20up%20to%20100%2C000%20people.)
- [Google Groups Membership](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6099642?hl=en#:%7E:text=That%20is%2C%20a%20Group%20can,member%20of%202%2C000%20Groups%20directly.&text=Note%3A%20This%20limitation%20also%20applies%20to%20Groups.,-That%20is%2C%20a)